# Symfony formbuilder: Skip one value

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I have a entity named Child, which has a ChildType as form, with a ChildRelation form injected in it.

In my code I currently have this, but this validates everything:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(ChildType::class, $child);
$editForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {}
```

Things got more complex, I need the form to process *all* values, with the errorhandling it does, except for the `$child->childrelations` array, I want that ignored completely. I want to do this manually. How can I do this without changing a lot of code?

I was thinking something in configureOptions, but I cant find the actual options I need to set then...

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony >= 3**

To validate a nested entity, you have to use the annotation: `@Assert\Valid` in your entity's field definition.

If you don't write this annotation, it will be not validated ( from Symfony 3.0)

**Symfony < 3.0**

You can add the  "cascade_validation' => false" option to your from field creation.

Comment: Hi, I'm not looking to skip validation, I want to skip updating all together

Comment: What Symfony version are you using?

Comment: Thats version  3.something

Comment: I see, so you want that, after `handleRequest()`, the values in `ChildRelation` get back to the original ones? (before the user submitting data)

Comment: That would become quite heavy, it updates, I revert and then update manually.

Comment: I'm sorry, but then I don't understand what you're trying to achieve...